# Как правильно подключиться к API используя Header Authorization Bearer, React.js и axios?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, axios

Заранее прошу прощения за такой вопрос, впервые использую React.
Нужно подключиться к API и взять с неё данные, после тчетных попыток обращаюсь к вам за помощью, скажите, где моя ошибка, в какую сторону смотреть, что я делаю не так ?!
Проверил в postman - подключается, видно json.
Спасибо !!!

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

const accessToken = "туть токен";
const apiUrl = "туть ссылка на API";

const authAxios = axios.create({
  baseUrl: apiUrl,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  },
});

function App() {
  const [payments, setPayments] = useState([]);
  const [requestError, setRequestError] = useState();

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const result = await authAxios.get(`/payments/all`);
      setPayments(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setRequestError(error.message);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <button onClick={() => fetchData()}> Get payments </button>
      {payments.map((payment) => {
        return <p key="payment.id"> {payment.id} </p>;
      })}
      {requestError && <p className="error"> {requestError} </p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

В итоге результат — [image: ошибка][image: консоль]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в постман куда запрос отправляете, по какому url?

Comment: По урлу самой API, в коде я точно так же её подставляю в apiUrl... к сожалению я не могу вам предоставить ссылку из соображений безопасности но могу прикрепить скрин на котором видно что запрос обрабатывается и сервер возвращает json. Возможно я неправильно выбираю путь по которому должен получить данные в (/payments/) ? https://tratata.dev/api/v1/payments

Comment: 404 ошибка значит, что вы указываете неправильный url. Поэтому внимательно посмотрите, на какой url вы отправляете запрос из postman. Кстати, вы запрос отправляете на `localhost:3000` - у вас сервер локально поднят для бакенда?

Comment: Вы знаете, нет, локально сервер не поднимал, как это можно сделать с реакт ?

Comment: Вы отправляете запрос на `localhost:3000`. По какому url у вас АПИ? Вот по тому адресу и делайте запрос! Реакт здесь абсолютно не при чем.

Comment: Хмм... я localhost в принципе нигде не прописывал, это по умолчанию реакт открывает страницу по этому адресу( а специально я нигде к нему не обращаюсь, урл https:// это никак не влияет на данную ситуацию ?

Comment: У вас запрос `authAxios.get('/payments/all')` - без указания адреса АПИ. Укажите правильный url, например  `authAxios.get('https://tratata.dev/payments/all')`.

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://tratata.dev/api/v1/payments/payments/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
xhr.js:177 GET https://tratata.dev/api/v1/payments/payments/ net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: кажется я просто неправильно отправляю запрос с использованием авторизации bearer, я впервые этим пользуюсь и пока не понимаю как это нужно сделать правильно(

Comment: Уже лучше! Теперь надо, что бы сервер `tratata.dev` разрешил сделать запрос от  `localhost:3000`. Как это сделать - гуглите CORS

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду гуглить, надеюсь найду все-таки решение. Я правильно понимаю, мне ненужен доступ к настройкам сервера ?

Comment: Да, правильно понимаете. Сервер должен разрешать отдавать вам данные.

Comment: TypeError: payments.map is not a function
return (
<div className="container">
<button onClick={() => fetchData()}> Get payments </button>
{payments.map((payment) => {
return <p key="payment.id"> {payment.id} </p>;})}
const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {try {
const result = await authAxios.get(`${apiUrl}?${accessToken}`);
setPayments(result.data);} catch (error) {
setRequestError(error.message);}
Я двигаюсь в правильном направление? Если вам не тяжело, подскажите пожалуйста, как прописать адрес url + header authorization bearer(token) и просмотреть данные используя браузер ?!

Comment: Задавайте новый вопрос, этот исчерпал себя. А читать код в комментах я не умею )

Comment: Извините это я от безысходности, вроде как не дают возможность вставки кода делать в коментах, но все же, у меня получилось, не знаю на сколько это плохо но отключил безопасность через флаг на ярлыке хрома(